# Docker TCP vs host port

Tags: docker, networking, tcp, mapping, port

can some one please help me on understanding this, I have a Dockerfile and dockercompose.yaml

When i do docker-compose up, I see the tcp being diffrent compared to the exposed ports, here is the file

```
> Dockerfile 
FROM msridhara/tomcat 
VOLUME /tmp  
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"] 
EXPOSE 81
```

```
>docker-compose.yaml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: msridtomcat
    build: .
    container_name: mcontainer
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/murali/website/containerjob/war/:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
#      - /home/ubuntu/webimage/index.html:/var/www/html/index.html
    ports:
      - "81:8080"
```

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
2cb36ee8c5ee        msridtomcat         "catalina.sh run"   58 seconds ago      Up 57 seconds       83/tcp, 0.0.0.0:81->8080/tcp   mcontainer
```

Please see the 83/tcp? from where it is coming?

```
docker inspect -- results in 
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "397ab289e556f8ee4b92c47e806a11a1f76d53cb398bdd5701e10e20a3362882",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "81"
                    }
                ],
                "83/tcp": null
            },
```

Thanks 
Murali

Comment: You'll see that if you have a port exposed but not published (your Dockerfile or the base image has `EXPOSE 83`, or the `docker-compose.yml` file has `expose: [83]`).  It's either harmless or an indication of a misconfiguration.  The `VOLUME` and `EXPOSE` in your Dockerfile both seem unnecessary, and the `ports:` don't seem to match up.

Comment: could you pls be kind and let me know how to change this? I do not have any thing set up in base image, the base image is just a tomcat image having tomcat.xml configured with manager user details

Comment: What port is Tomcat actually listening on?  (Ignore everything Docker-related, what's in the Tomcat settings?)

Comment: I tried to open tomcat on aws private ip:81 it opens with http 404, but if i change the ip as provate ip:81/snapshot.war -- then it is accessible and i cannot access tomcat on privateip:83... But the strange thing is if I change the Dockerfile and compose.yaml with port 83 then tomcat homepage is displayed with privateip:83

Comment: ```docker port mcontainer -- (container name)
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:81   docker port mcontainer 8080/tcp
0.0.0.0:81

Comment: Does [this Dockerfile line](https://github.com/msridhara/websi/blob/master/Dockerfile#L7) correspond to the image you're running?  Or [this Docker hub image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/msridhara/tomcat/latest/images/sha256-bf83ed91cf2e2eac9050b0b90067f2872ea370dd1dcc7f49bce0cadc5ba933e4?context=explore)?

Comment: That the image i uploaded to dockerhub, custom version of tomcat-- I just changed the tomcat.xml so that i do not need to add the users everytime i run it

Comment: The `EXPOSE 83` in the linked Dockerfile from the base image leads to that part of the `docker ps` output.

Comment: Please suggest how to get rid of that, I am lost here

Comment: Thank you David for the hint. I solved it

Answer (score 1):

This tcp 83 is due to Expose 83 in Dockerfile. Just removed the Expose from Dockerfile and exposed the port via docker-compose yaml. All worked well